# How to add property to vertex property in java?

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I want to add property to a vertex property. In gremlin i add property "phone" to vertex property "places" that has value is "place1"

```
g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('place1').property('phone',"123456789")
```

It worked ok without using transaction commit. But when i used this way in java code, it not worked. So in java code, how to add a property to vertex property?
Thank for your help.

Comment: Your code above seems to work against TinkerGraph.  what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: it not throw exception, it just not work when i want to save a property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `iterate()` the traversal.

```
g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('place1').property('phone',"123456789").iterate()
```

One way to think about: the original code snippet is the query, but then you still need to execute it.

Here's a full Gremlin Console example that shows the difference.

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('inmemory'); g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> v = graph.addVertex('name','jenny','places','home')
==>v[4264]
gremlin> g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home')
==>vp[places->home]
gremlin> g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home').property('phone','867-5309'); 'traversal was not iterated'
==>traversal was not iterated
gremlin> g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home').properties()
gremlin> g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home').property('phone','867-5309').iterate(); 'iterated!'
==>iterated!
gremlin> g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home').properties()
==>p[phone->867-5309]
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
==>null
```

You need to commit the transaction if you want the data to be persisted.

Comment: One more question, how to drop vertex property has value 'home''? In this way it not work g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home').drop() . Thank you again

Comment: Same answer as before, you need to `iterate()`, so `g.V(v).properties('places').hasValue('home').drop().iterate()`.